# Equivalent of BufferedImage (java awt) on JavaFx

Tags: javafx, bufferedimage

I'm working with JavaFx and i'm looking for an equivalent of the `AWT BufferedImage`. I saw that I can used `SwingFXUtils` to used an `awt BufferedImage` with JavaFx but I don't want to used `awt`.

In fact I'm looking for a structure to display a table of pixel witch is associated to a `ColorModel`.

Does anybody know some equivalent with JavaFx ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The closest you get to a `BufferedImage` in JavaFX is [`javafx.scene.image.WritableImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/WritableImage.html). It is a subclass of `javafx.scene.image.Image`, and was introduced in JavaFX 2.2.

Depending on your use case, `javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas` and `javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext` (similar to a `Graphics2D` Java2D) might be a better fit.

To paint on a `Canvas` node and get the contents in a `WritableImage`, use (adapted from the `Canvas` JavaDoc):

```
// Create canvas
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(250, 250);
GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

// Paint on it
gc.setFill(Color.BLUE);
gc.fillRect(75, 75, 100, 100);

// NOTE: The canvas must be part of a Scene for the following to work properly, omitted for brevity

// Obtain a snapshot of the canvas
WritableImage image = canvas.snapshot(null, null);
```

See [Working with Canvas](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/canvas/jfxpub-canvas.htm) from he JavaFX tutorials for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried WritableImage but it's not enough performant. If I want to change the color of each pixel, I've to do a "for" on each pixel. It's very slow. Do you know if there is an other way ?

Comment: WriteableImage performs very well in my (limited) experience. See my answer [here, reading an image from file in 40-60ms](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24135889/1428606). But it may not suit your use case. Maybe `javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas` and `javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext` is more what you are looking for?

Comment: In fact I have a table of value (Each element of the table correspond to one pixel). And I want to associate each value to a color and then display the table. But the values of the table change everytime. So I have to change the color of each pixel in real-time.

Comment: I think I have answered your question as accurately as I can. If you want help with something else, please post a new question, describing what you want to solve, and the code you have so far. It sounds to me like your best bet is `Canvas`, other people might have other/better ideas. :-)

Comment: Thank you, I'll post a new question for more details.